# Ubuntu as VPN router

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, vpn

Here's my situation:

1. Remote network (10.0.0.x) in another city, with a Cisco VPN router
2. Windows server (local) that I want to have on the same subnet as remote network

On the Windows server I've installed Ubuntu (using Virtual Box) and created two VM network interfaces:

1. Bridged network adapter (to get the Ubuntu VM internet access)
2. Host-only adapter (to link the VM and Windows server)

Next, I want to:

1. Create an always-on VPN connection to the remote network in Ubuntu
2. Share this VPN connection using bridged mode to the Windows server, using the host-only network adapter

I can do internet connection sharing (ICS) but this seems to be NAT-only. How do I share the VPN connection to the host-only adapter using bridged mode?